# Trying to understand MVVM sample posted by Google

Tags: android, dagger-2

Folks,

I am trying to understand the code sample posted by google related to the android architecture. I am going through the GithubBrowserSample (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) and trying to create my own project to better understand it. However I am stuck , as I am not able to understand how is the "NavigationController.java" class is being instantiated. 
Because in my project when I am trying to run, I am getting a null pointed exception where I am trying to call "NavigationController.navigateToSearch"

Can you please help guys here.

The linke to my GitHub repository is 
https://github.com/saunaklogan/DemoArchitecture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class NavigationController {
    private final int containerId;
    private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    @Inject
    public NavigationController(MainActivity mainActivity) {
```

We see that it has an Inject constructor, so Dagger2 will see it. We also see that there is no scope annotation on this class, so unless this is bound in a module to a given scope, it'll be unscoped. And it receives MainActivity as an argument, so it'll be instantiated by a component that knows about MainActivity.

There is only a single activity in the app and there are multiple fragments, so all it takes is to use Activity scoped subcomponent to inject the activity.

This is automatic, as it is done by the [AppInjector](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.java#L44) when the Activity is created, and calls `AndroidInjection.inject(activity)` which looks up the Activity scoped component that can inject MainActivity.

```
public class AppInjector {
    private AppInjector() {}
        public static void init(GithubApp githubApp) {
            DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(githubApp)
                  .build().inject(githubApp);
            githubApp
                  .registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
                      @Override
                      public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                          handleActivity(activity);
                      }
```

And it is initialized in Application class.

```
public class GithubApp extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        }
        AppInjector.init(this); // <--
    }
```

The definition of the subcomponent that binds the instance of `MainActivity` is in [MainActivityModule](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/MainActivityModule.java#L26).

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = FragmentBuildersModule.class)
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();
}
```

Which is added to the global component.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        MainActivityModule.class
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have been trying to run my own project which is very similar to the sample but with just one fragment, but I am not able to get it to execute as it is giving me a null pointer exception in MainActivity

 if(savedInstanceState == null){
            navigationController.navigateToPosts();
        }

Comment: Then you are missing the AppInjector, or the @ContributesAndroidInjector submodule from the app global component. Or the call to `AndroidInjection.inject(activity)`. Or the `AndroidInjectionModule.class`.

Comment: I have cross checked again and I see all the components to be present. But I am still getting the error

Comment: There is zero way for me to tell you the cause without seeing the code, you know :D if you have a github repo to look at, that's great - otherwise people will lock this question [saying it has no minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks again .. here is my GitHub link can you please point me the problem here
https://github.com/saunaklogan/DemoArchitecture

Comment: `if(activity instanceof HasActivityInjector) {  AndroidInjection.inject(activity)` the if statement is wrong. Although I think you should just remove that `if`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168643/discussion-between-saunlogan-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: You didn't specify `<application android:name=".DemoArchitecture"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`